# SWAGGER: Parser error on line 27 end of the stream or a document separator is expected

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.3.5, swagger

When i try to get the API schema from swagger for an actuve customer y get this error

Parser error on line 27 end of the stream or a document separator is expected

https://magento.farmagsa.com.ar/swagger

And the customer TEST key is:

f5s39z4o1zcdzpr7auorhl5fltqwkfpe